# How to use CASE in SQL for different conditions

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use conditions with case in sql but not getting any proper solution,

Here is my Query :

```
select users.id
     , friends.user_id
     , friends.friend_id
     , CASE WHEN friends.accept IS NULL THEN  10
             WHEN friends.friend_id = 18 THEN friends.accept = 11
             else friends.accept = Same
END AS friend_status
from users 
  left 
  join friends 
    on users.id = friends.friend_id 
 where users.id != 18 
 order 
    by id asc
```

I just want that,

1. WHEN friends.accept IS NULL THEN  10
2. WHEN friends.friend_id = 18 THEN friends.accept = 11
3. else friends.accept = Same as in table

Is it possible, If possible Please help me out

Comment: What is `friends.accept = 11` meant to mean? Do you want to **assign**  (`UPDATE`)`friends.accept` - or do you want to **compare equality**? What does `Same` mean?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
select users.id, friends.user_id, friends.friend_id, 
CASE 
WHEN friends.accept IS NULL THEN 10
WHEN friends.friend_id = 18 THEN 11
ELSE friends.accept
END AS friend_status
from users left join friends on users.id = friends.friend_id where users.id != 18 order by id asc
```